# Can't find libasound_module_pcm_a52.la and .so when trying to fix surround sound

Tags: 14.04, sound

Running Ubuntu Using 14.04.2, I'm following the guide for 5.1 through spdif [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio) and have done it both manually and using the script. What ever I do, I stop at the point when I need to copy `libasound_module_pcm_a52.la` and `libasound_module_pcm_a52.so`.

I can't find them anywhere on my system. I've tried reinstalling the plugin package but it's the same.

*Anyone has any ideas on what to do?*

Comment: Based on the instructions you linked, the `.la` and `.so` files should be in an `a52/.libs` subdirectory, and should have been created by the preceding `libtoolize ... && make` command(s) - did those commands complete **without errors**? If you are not sure then please edit your post to include the output of the final `make` command.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Did you start following that procedure from the top?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `locate libasound_module_pcm_a52.la` and `locate libasound_module_pcm_a52.so` and see what they return.

I belive you mentioned you may have already installed this but please confirm if you have installed this package: `libasound2-plugins`.

Comment: Locate doesn't return any result and the package is already installed. :( See answer below for terminal output (can't get formatting to work here).

Comment: $ sudo locate libasound_module_pcm_a52.so
$ sudo locate libasound_module_pcm_a52.la
$
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libasound2-plugins is already the newest version.
libasound2-plugins set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
$

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: You do need to compile it as described on the page you [linked](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio).

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04: The package `libasound2-plugins` was installed according to Ubuntu's software center and some files belonging to it could be `locate`d.

However, I got

```
aplay -D a52:0 chan-id.wav 
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:254:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_a52.so
```

Thus, I compiled it as described on the page linked above, copied it

```
sudo cp ./tmp/alsa-plugins-1.0.25/a52/.libs/libasound_module_pcm_a52.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_a52.so
```

and after that it worked:

```
aplay -D a52:0 chan-id.wav 
Wiedergabe: WAVE 'chan-id.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate: 44100 Hz, 6 Kanäle
```